# When trying to use Card of Reactstrap I get Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components, reactstrap

I tried to import the Card component from the Reactstrap library, and unfortunately this has resulted in the error below.

```
React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

When I remove the  element, the page works again as intended.

IMPORTS (IN PROFILE COMPONENT):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card, Container, Table} from 'reactstrap';
```

EXPORT (AT BOTTOM OF PROFILE COMPONENT):

```
export default Profile;
```

In APP.js router:

```
<Route path='/profile' exact={true} component={Profile}/>
```

Full Profile component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card, Container, Table} from 'reactstrap';
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar';

const GET_SINGLE_USER_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/users/get-user-by-username'

class Profile extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {user: '', token: ''};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const payload = {
            "username": localStorage.getItem("username"),
            "password": localStorage.getItem("password")
        };
        fetch(GET_SINGLE_USER_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({user: data}));
    }

    render() {
        const {user, isLoading} = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <AppNavbar/>
                <Container fluid>
                    <h3 className="player-list-header">Profile</h3>

                    <Table className="mt-4">
                        <thead>
                        <tr id="player-list-row">
                            <th className="player-list-data-text">Name</th>
                            <th className="player-list-data-text">Username</th>
                            <th className="player-list-data-text">Location</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr key={user.id}>
                            <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} className="player-list-key-text">{user.name}</td>
                            <td className="player-list-key-text">{user.username}</td>
                            <td className="player-list-key-text">{user.location}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body>This is some text within a card body.</Card.Body>
                    </Card>


                </Container>
            </div>
        );

    }

}
export default Profile;
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code, ideally a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order for folks to be able to help here.

Comment: I guess you have [this problem](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13445#issuecomment-414389398) with your `Profile` component

Comment: @BrendanBond I added the code for the Profile component, sorry.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Hello, I added the code for the Profile component, and I understand what you mean - the user data elements that display info aren't in a function, but that part of the component still works when I remove the <card>, so I am unsure what to do. Thanks.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I just triedt this but displayUserData isn't a function, I don't know how to do this.  const currentUser = displayUserData(user => {
            return <tr key={user.id}>
                <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} class="player-list-key-text">{user.name}</td>
                <td class="player-list-key-text">{user.username}</td>
                <td class="player-list-key-text">{user.location}</td>
            </tr>
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might not have read reactstrap's docs closely enough - the component should be `CardBody`, not `Card.Body`. [Here's a link to the docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-card--card), and a [simplified CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cherry-hb3h1?file=/src/Profile.jsx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did copy and paste it from a tutorial, maybe it was a bootstrap instead of reactstrap.